# git svn dcommit: Chokes on .DS_Store

Tags: git, svn, dcommit

Yes, I know I should have had .DS_Store in my .gitignore!!  I messed up :(

I wasn't paying attention and .DS_Store crept in...  But now, for whatever reason, I get the following when doing a dcommit:

```
% git svn dcommit
Committing to http://[...]/trunk ...
    A       public/images/jquery-ui/smoothness/.DS_Store
URL access forbidden for unknown reason: access to '/svn/softeng/!svn/wrk/d346c9aa-810d-4ef6-8852-65b5d36ecc06/tools/escalate/trunk/public/images/jquery-ui/smoothness/.DS_Store' forbidden at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 579
```

Anyone understand why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [interactive rebase](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) in stead of an `amend` and edit an earlier commit.

More info on the process:

- [Interactive rebase](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html)
- [Interactive rebase](http://help.github.com/rebase/)